# GoDaddy charges me taxes, but not my wife nor my co-workers

Tags: domains, godaddy

I have been with GoDaddy for over 8 years now. I register about 20 domains per month for my customers, mainly .com domains.

I live in Ireland. When I am on checkout on GoDaddy, I have never ever been charged any taxes.
Last month, I have signed up for GoDaddys domain club at a price of $120/year to get a bigger discount on my domains.
Usually I pay $9.92 for a .com domain, and with the domain club membership, I am paying $8.29.

I registered about 30 domains last month again, and the new price of $8.29 was applied, every single time, still no taxes.

Last week I registered new domains again, and I suddenly see the price was $10.49. I logged in and out of my account, thinking there might be an error.
Nothing changed. I contacted GoDaddy support and they were asking if I did consider the taxes. I went to the checkout page, and indeed, it's now taxing me 23%, which is Irelands VAT.
I told the support this is strange, because over the past 8 years I was never charged any tax. Their support replied I should contact my government about the taxes, and they can't change the tax rate (obviously!).

So I accepted the fact that GoDaddy is now suddenly charging taxes.

A few days later however, I noticed when my Wife register a .com domain, she wasn't charged any taxes. Her GoDaddy account has the exact same address as mine, except she isn't in the GoDaddy domain club.
My Wife has since then register another 10 domains, all without paying taxes.

She is paying $9.92 for a .com domain and I am paying $10.49 and on top of that paid $120/year to be part of the domain club, where I should get it cheaper.

I thought this is a mistake on her account. I then contacted 7 other web developers here in Ireland, and 5 other ones across Europe and asked them if they are being charged taxes on GoDaddy. EVERY SINGLE ONE confirmed, that they are NOT being charged any taxes and NONE of them are with GoDaddy domain club.

I then created a new GoDaddy account, same name and address as my primary account, and... no taxes!

I have contacted GoDaddy support 5 times now, and told them exactly what I wrote here, and all they keep saying is that GoDaddy is not in charge of taxes, and if I don't agree with the tax rate, I should call my government. They say GoDaddy must comply with each countries tax rate as seen here: https://ie.godaddy.com/help/godaddy-taxes-outside-the-united-states-24726
and GoDaddy has and always will charge taxes... which is complete and utter BS, considering I have never been charges taxes on domains in 8 years, and I have proof that they don't charge anyone else any taxes in my country and other EU country, and even creating a new account shows that there are no taxes being added.

What I find incredibly strange is, that the exact same month that I sing up for GoDaddy domain club, I am being charged taxes for every domain, which in the end made it more expensive to purchase any domains.

Does anyone else have a similar issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal issue or customer support issue. You should contact godaddy directly to find out why their tax charging seems to deviate from what you expect.